# Compare Key-value pairs in a hash in perl

Tags: perl, compare, hash

I have a hash with key values as a scalar string. The value is another hash which has the words of the string as key and their frequency as value.

structure:

```
 { 
  doc1 => { w1 => freq1 , w2 => freq2, .....} ,
  doc2 => { w1 => freq1 , w2 => freq2, .....} ,
  .
  .
  .
}
```

I want to compare two keys(doc1, doc2...) and find common words between two docs. The output required is sum of frequencies of the common words between two docs, for all pairs of docs.

Which is the best way to do it?

Comment: What have you tried? What problems did you encounter? Please show your Perl code, and an example of input and required output. Please read [*How do I ask a good question?*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

# Sum of frequencies
my @frequencies;

# First doc
my $doc1 = {
    w1 => 1 , w2 => 5, w3 => 1
};

# Second doc
my $doc2 = {
    w1 => 3 , w2 => 2, w3 => 1, w4 => 12
};

# see first doc
foreach my $word (keys %{$doc1}) {
    if (exists $doc2->{$word}) {
        push (@frequencies, {$word => $doc1->{$word} + $doc2->{$word}});
    }
    else {
        push (@frequencies, {$word => $doc1->{$word}});
    }

    delete $doc2->{$word};
}

# see second doc
foreach my $word (keys %{$doc2}) {
    push (@frequencies, {$word => $doc2->{$word}});
}

# See sum of frequencies
print join "\n", map {sprintf("%s: %s", keys %$_, values %$_)} @frequencies;

1;
```

output

```
$ perl compare.pl
w3: 2
w1: 4
w2: 7
w4: 12
```